# PHP, display mysql row in view

Tags: php, sql

I'm having trouble displaying the sql below in the hph view file.

```
 $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT TF.tf_ID AS QuestID, TF.Question AS Question FROM QuizQuestions quest, addTF TF WHERE quest.QuestID = TF.tf_ID AND quest.QuizID ='".$quizID."'  AND quest.Type = 'tf'");
 $rows = array();
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
 }
 echo json_encode($rows);
```

This is the part of the php view that is supposed to display the sql. I know it is wrong but I don't know how to fix it. Any help is welcome.

```
<?php foreach($json as $tf) :?> <?php echo $tf['Question']; ?> <div class="row-fluid"><div class="span8">
<div class="btn view" id="view" style="width: 98%">
<p class="text-left" style="margin: 0;float: left;">
<input type ="hidden" value="tf" name="type">
<input type="checkbox" id="questID" value="<?php echo $tf['tf_ID'];?>" name="questID" class="questID"  > <?php echo 'Question: '.$tf['Question']; ?> </input><br/>
<input type="hidden"> <?php echo 'Answer: '.$tf['Answer'] ; ?> </input><br/>
  </div> </div> </div> <?php endforeach; ?>
```

I've used similar codes and they work. They problem is I do not know how to work with sql "AS". My apology in advance if this question was once asked and for the format.

Comment: First things first: Your checkbox isn't set right. `input` is a self closing tag.

Comment: Clean your code please.

Comment: First things first: There's probably a SQLInjection in your code. Fix that first or your little browsergame will be hacked soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method called mysqli_fetch_assoc(). There is mysql_fetch_assoc() but **not** mysqli_fetch_assoc().

You can do this to get the rows:

```
$query = "SELECT TF.tf_ID AS QuestID, TF.Question AS Question FROM QuizQuestions quest, addTF TF WHERE quest.QuestID = TF.tf_ID AND quest.QuizID ='".$quizID."'  AND quest.Type = 'tf'";


$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

If you are calling the query through an Ajax method and returning the data to JavaScript you should JSON encode. However, if you are just printing the rows with PHP there is no reason to JSON encode them.

To iterate the rows in PHP you can do:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<div>' . $row['foo']; . '</div><div>' . $row['bar']; . '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I used something similar to your php to get my output.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not clear what you are trying to do.

The top code create some JSON which will be sent to the browser. Presumably in response to a AJAX or jQuery request. Once the JSON is on the browser it can be added to the current page using Java-Script.

The second code fragment is PHP which always executes on the server, but your data is on the client???

I would have expected something more like...

```
$rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)
echo "<div>\n";
foreach($rows as $row) {
   // generate one row getting values as {$row['fieldname']} 

}
echo "</div>";
```

Also - if you don't generate 100% valid and error free html you not only have to test on all current browsers, you cannot complain if a new browser displays it wrongly next release.

Comment: There is no mysqli_fetch_assoc(); There is mysql_fetch_assoc(). To do the equivalent in mysqli it would be mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);